# Boolean algebra how does $A'(B' *C+ B* C')$ simplify?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Does $A'(B' *C+ B* C')$ simplify to $A'(1)$? 
I'm a bit confused because I know that $A+A' *B = A +B$ so I'm wondering what happens in the above situation. I know this might be related to the two variable rule.

Note $*$ represents AND and $+$ represents OR

Thanks

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes! I edited the question to be clearer!  And I made a typo in my equation that just fixed

Comment: This is false. Take $A=0, B=0,C=0$, then the left hand side evaluates to $0$ but $A'(1)$ evaluates to $1$.

Comment: If you are stuck, with a small number of variables, just do a truth table.

Comment: Never heard of the two variable rule.

Comment: Unless you are allowed to use an XOR this doesn't really simplify.

Comment: @copper.hat in this situation we're aiming to not use a xor

Comment: OK, you see why the equation does not simplify to $A'$?

Comment: This statement is true only when only one of $B$, $C$ is true. The inside term is an XOR, so you really have $A'(B\oplus C)$. You could rewrite as $A'(B+C)(B'+C')$ but that doesn't seem any simpler.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm getting there but if it is true that A+A' B = A + B? Then I'm wondering why in that case the A' disappears. Unless I'm mistaking a Boolean rule

Comment: $A+A'B = A+AB + A'B = A+ B(A+A') = A+B$. (Because $A $ always implies $AB$, so you can include it without changing anything.) Again, use a truth table to validate for small number of variables.

Comment: That doesn't quite work here though since you need a variable by itself with its negation ANDed with another variable @KatieMelosto

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much Cameron Williams and @copper.hat  this has been very helpful to me!